# How to prevent “Table X was locked with a READ lock and can't be updated”?

Tags: mysql

I am using a MySQL table with date ranges. These date ranges may overlap, e. g. a date range from `2019-01-01` to `2019-01-10` and a second date range from `2019-01-05` to `2019-01-15`. I need the combined date range for a time calculation, in the example, it would be `2019-01-01` to `2019-01-15`. I wrote a procedure that creates a temporary table with the combined results.

Some functions use this temporary table for some time calculations. These functions call the procedure to create a temporary table, if not exists. But if the temporary table already exists, I get the error “Table was locked with a READ lock and can't be updated”. If I drop the temporary table before calling the create procedure, I do not get an error. But then every time the temporary table must be created again and the query takes almost a second to complete.

How can I prevent the error without dropping the temporary table every time?

Example:

```
drop database if exists TempTestDB;
create database TempTestDB;
USE `TempTestDB`;

create table TestTable(
test int auto_increment not null primary key,
name varchar(45))
;

-- real table has time data
INSERT INTO TestTable (`name`) VALUES ('test1');

DROP procedure IF EXISTS `createTempTestTable`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `TempTestDB`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`riedel`@`%` PROCEDURE `createTempTestTable`()
BEGIN

-- the temp table contains merged rows of the base table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTestTable select * from TestTable;

INSERT INTO TempTestTable (`name`) VALUES ('test2');

END$$

DELIMITER ;

USE `TempTestDB`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `TempTestDB`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `getTimeForUser`(user int) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

-- real function does some time calculation

declare result int;

call TempTestDB.createTempTestTable;

select count(*) from TempTestTable into result;

RETURN result;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

select TempTestDB.getTimeForUser(1) union select TempTestDB.getTimeForUser(2);drop database if exists TempTestDB;
create database TempTestDB;
USE `TempTestDB`;

create table TestTable(
test int auto_increment not null primary key,
name varchar(45))
;

-- real table has time data
INSERT INTO TestTable (`name`) VALUES ('test1');

DROP procedure IF EXISTS `createTempTestTable`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `TempTestDB`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`riedel`@`%` PROCEDURE `createTempTestTable`()
BEGIN

-- the temp table contains merged rows of the base table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTestTable select * from TestTable;

INSERT INTO TempTestTable (`name`) VALUES ('test2');

END$$

DELIMITER ;

USE `TempTestDB`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `TempTestDB`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `getTimeForUser`(user int) RETURNS INT
BEGIN

-- real function does some time calculation

declare result int;

call TempTestDB.createTempTestTable;

select count(*) from TempTestTable into result;

RETURN result;

END$$

DELIMITER ;

select TempTestDB.getTimeForUser(1) union select TempTestDB.getTimeForUser(2);
```

Comment: Can you add the procedure, an example function,a statement which invokes the function, sample data and expected output.(all as text)